# Операции с датой (formatDate) в библиотеке JSTL

Tags: jstl, java, jsp

Пишем в jsp:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${myTimestamp}" pattern="HH:mm, EEEE, dd MMM yyyy" var="time"/>
```

Результат:

```
19:16, понедельник, 07 мар 2011
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы выводилось так:

```
19:16 (вчера)
19:16 (позавчера)
```

и т.д.
Возможно ли сделать это с помощью JSTL FMT formatDate?

---

Был найден такой вариант:

переменная ${now} равна кол-ву дней с начала года

```
<fmt:formatDate value="<%=new Date()%>" var="now" pattern="D"/>
```

таким же образом получаем свой день, вычитаем один из другого и получаем кол-во дней, которое прошло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, нельзя. Но вы всегда можете написать свою кастомную функцию, которая отформатирует вам как надо и прописать её через TLD, а подом в JSP подключить и использовать.

Например (упрощённо):

Класс реализация (здесь реализуете нужную логику форматирования)

```
private class MyDataFormatter {
    public static String formatDate(Date date) {
        // my format implementation in Java
    }
}
```

Создаёте TLD-дескриптор (описываете функции, которые можно будет использовать в JSP, в том числе и без JSTL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>myDateFunctions</short-name>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/myDateFunctions</uri>

  <function>
      <name>formatDate</name>
      <function-class>my.package.MyDataFormatter</function-class>
      <function-signature>java.lang.String formatDate(java.util.Date date)</function-signature>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

Подключаете и используете в JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefox="dd" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/myDateFunctions" %>

<!-- какой-то код -->

<span class="date-node">${dd:formatDate(item.date)}</span>

<!- дальще какой-то код -->
```

Comment: Фигова, что нельзя. Этот метод хороший, попробую! Но нашел ещё один другой, напишу позже, спасибо.

Comment: Конечно хороший. Таким образом можно наделать кучу таких вспомогательных функций, которых не хватает и везде юзать, так как подключать их очень просто.

Comment: Добавил свой вариант выше.

Comment: А какие библиотеки для этого нужны, чтобы использовать свои теги?

Comment: Никакие. Только JavaEE.

Comment: Да, но ведь ваш вариант не делает то что требуется..

Comment: Я extend-ю от TagSupport, так вот нет этого класса в класспас( Или не надо экстендить?

Comment: Если вы не хотите делать кастомный тэг, а хотите просто функцию для EL, то не надо ничего экстендить.. делаете просто класс, как у меня в примере